# How to best overlay a canvas on an image?

Tags: html, image, canvas, overlay, positioning

I would like to place a canvas on top of an image that I have on a page. The canvas will be the exact dimensions of the image.

However, the following conditions must be met:

- The canvas must remain **exactly** on top of the image at all times. Therefore, using absolute positioning will not work because if content is inserted above the image, it will move the image down *without moving the canvas*.
- The image may be resized from its original size. Therefore, replacing the image with the canvas and setting its background to the image will not work.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `position:relative` instead of absolute for your first requirement.

For the second I'm guessing you could put both the image and the canvas inside of a span.  The canvas would have a width/height of 100% and would be resized as the image resizes because the size of the div would change to fit the image.

EDIT: actually I'm not sure `position:relative` would work.  But I believe if you use `position:absolute` and the parent element has `position:relative`, than the absolute positions will be relative to the parent.

Comment: I tried `relative` on the canvas, but it leads to other trouble - the browser will allocate room for the element even though it won't be there.

Comment: **Thank you!** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dGqG5/) is a fiddle that demonstrates that your answer is correct. +1 and accept!

Comment: Excellent.  I didn't have time to test it out myself so I'm glad it worked