# HTML5 - Display Typed Text from Textarea on Image

Tags: html, canvas

I want to display the typed text ( If a person types text in a `textarea` the text should be immediately visible On an image)  on an image. I have developed following code but it`s not showing anything on image.. sorry i am a newbie in HTML5, please advise

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
         context.font = "40pt Calibri";
         context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);
     };
     imageObj.src = "smallimage.jpg"; 
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
<textarea onchange="test();" id="txtContents"></textarea>
<img src="smallimage.jpg" id="myCanvas">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your "img" tag should be a "canvas" tag.  Also, with the way you have it currently, The image is reloaded every time a user types in the text area.  I would recommend laying the canvas directly on top of the image and then just clearing the canvas and redrawing the text onchange().  Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeText(textarea){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var text = textarea.value;
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.fillText(text, 20, 20);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<textarea onkeyup="changeText(this);" id="txtContents"></textarea>
<div class="outer">
<img src="smallimage.jpg" class="box" id="myImage" />
<canvas class="box" id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#myImage {

}

#myCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Check out: [How to best overlay a canvas on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330942/how-to-best-overlay-a-canvas-on-an-image) for laying the canvas directly on top of the image.  The accepted answer has a fiddle in the comments that shows how to do it.

Comment: ...and you'll want to use onkeyup instead of onchange since onchange is only fired when the user leaves the textarea. Here is an example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NuaHp/